# Django 3.2.3 Pagination isn't working properly

Tags: django, django-pagination, django-3.2

I have a Class Based View who isn't working properly (duplicating objects and deleting some)
Tested it in shell

```
from django.core.paginator import Paginator
from report.models import Grade, Exam

f = Exam.objects.all().filter(id=7)[0].full_mark
all = Grade.objects.all().filter(exam_id=7, value__gte=(f*0.95)).order_by('-value')
p = Paginator(all, 12)
for i in p.page(1).object_list:
...     print(i.id)
```

2826
2617
2591
2912
2796
2865
2408
2501
2466
2681
2616
**2563**

```py
for i in p.page(2).object_list:
...     print(i.id)
```

2558
2466
**2563**
2920
2681
2824
2498
2854
2546
2606
2598
2614

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making an `order_by` call before passing the query_set `all` to the pagination is the root of the problem and well explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31736700/duplicate-elements-in-django-paginate-after-order-by-call). All you need is to call `distinct()` or specify another field in the `order_by` to use in case of same `value`.

Below is the code that should work, you also don't need to use `all()` in your queries. The filter by default applies on all the model objects.

```
from django.core.paginator import Paginator
from report.models import Grade, Exam

f = Exam.objects.filter(id=7).first().full_mark
all = Grade.objects.filter(exam_id=7, value__gte=(f*0.95)).order_by('-value').distinct()
p = Paginator(all, 12)
for i in p.page(1).object_list:
...     print(i.id)
```

By the way, your code will crash if an exam object with `id=7` is not found. You should assign the `full_mark` value to your `f` variable conditionally.